# How to make FBX model climbing on a slope

Tags: unity-game-engine

Related to the image below:
[image]
The Tank is a FBX model, imported with "Generate Colliders" checked. I want to make the tank walking the slope in front of it, which is just a resize cube from Unity ediftor. I tried different approaches : I added a rigidbody to the tank (receiving a message error), I added rigidbody to the cube. Nothing works.

This is my Tank Setting Capture

[image]

Could you help me ?

Comment: Can you share Tank & cube gameobject settings capture?

Answer (score 0):

You Should Uncheck the 'Is Trigger' Option for that cube, So that it'll stop Your Tank colliding in to the Cube

[image]

Comment: The cube is created from Unity editor. By default, "Is Trigger" option is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could try is implementing NavMesh and NavMeshAgent in your tank and environment. NavMeshAgent allows you to choose how big objects the agent can ignore and how steep slope it can cross etc.

Basic NavMesh implementation can be found on the unity docs: [Unity Building navmesh](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html)

Remember to set all the environment as navigation static from the navigation menu in order for agent to realize that it can climb over them etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit silly, but do you have a mesh collider added to the tank object?